# Can I use my Computer as a Headset for another device?

Tags: audio, headset

I have another device with a standard headset jack (TRRS), but I'd like to use the microphone and speakers on my laptop as the headset - audio conference style.  I have an interface to connect that device to USB - is there a way that I can plug that USB Audio adapter into my laptop and use my PC Microphone and Speaker to talk to the other device?

Answer (score 0):

No, the situation you describe is not possible without the purchase of additional audio hardware.